# php array operations append element

Tags: php, arrays

i have a small issue im creating multi table and im stuck,
i want to create something like this:

`1 table: [4,5,6]`
`2 table: [7,2,7,8]`
`3 table: [1,1,1]`
`4 table: [6,0,9]`

but each table can be of different size,
expected result:

```
[[4,7,1,6], [5,2,1,0], [6,7,1,9], [8]]
```

i was trying to make it using `for` loop but no success so far?

array should be builded this way:
first element is collection of all t1[0] + t2[0] + t3[0] ...
second element is collection of all t1[1] + t2[1] + t3[1] ...
...
and so on

Comment: php doesn't support using square bracket for array

Comment: @PankajKhairnar: Yes it does. Everyone else: Chatspeak ("u", "ur" etc.) is not welcome on SO.

Comment: @Pankaj - I suggest you reread the PHP documentation about arrays

Comment: @MarkBaker : I wasn't know php's version 5.4 and above is supporting square brackets for array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ([[4,5,6], [7,2,7,8], [1,1,1], [6,0,9]] as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        $result[$key2][$key] = $value2;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This does have the side effect of turning the last array into an associative array with key `"1"` (index 0 is empty), which is not exactly the result the OP was looking for.

Comment: @Asad - that can easily be fixed by doing $result = array_map('array_values', $result); but it depends how critical the keys are as to whether this is actually needed

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach (array(array(4,5,6), array(7,2,7,8), array(1,1,1), array(6,0,9)) as $k1 => $v1) {
    foreach($v1 as $k2 => $v2){
        if(!isset($result[$k2])){
            $result[$k2] = array();
        }
        $result[$k2][] = $v2;
    }
}

//output: [[4,7,1,6],[5,2,1,0],[6,7,1,9],[8]]
```

Here is a demonstration: http://codepad.org/lxJt4zOp